# Having some problems with SalesByQtr Assignment

Tags: java

I have an assignment that requires me to make the SalesByQtr java program i've gotten most of the program done but I have a couple of problems

**Firstly:** My total is being displayed as a double which I know I need printf to add a decimal place. The same thing is happening for Average.

**Second:** My division with the highest sales is saying Division 1 has the highest sales in qtr 1 and it repeats this in each qtr also Division 1 does not have the highest sales

**Finally:** My assignment requires that in qtrs 2-4 to display the change in sales and I can't figure out how to do that.

Here is the example output my professor is looking for

Example Output (bullet points represent spaces)

```
Q1:
   D1:·1000.00↵
   D2:·1700.00↵
   D3:·300.00↵
   D4:·2000.00↵
   D5:·1400.00↵
   D6:·500.00↵
Total:·6900.00↵
Average·sales:·1150.00↵
Division·with·highest·sales:4↵
Q2:
   D1:·2500.00,·Change:·1500.00↵
   D2:·500.00,·Change:·-1200.00↵
   D3:·700.00,·Change:·400.00↵
   D4:·2500.00,·Change:·500.00↵
   D5:·1450.00,·Change:·50.00↵
   D6:·1050.00,·Change:·550.00↵
Total:·8700.00,·Change:·1800.00↵
Average·sales:·1450.00↵
Division·with·highest·sales:1↵
Q3:
   D1:·3000.00,·Change:·500.00↵
   D2:·1000.00,·Change:·500.00↵
   D3:·120.00,·Change:·-580.00↵
   D4:·2700.00,·Change:·200.00↵
   D5:·980.00,·Change:·-470.00↵
   D6:·750.00,·Change:·-300.00↵
Total:·8550.00,·Change:·-150.00↵
Average·sales:·1425.00↵
Division·with·highest·sales:1↵
Q4:
   D1:·2700.00,·Change:·-300.00↵
   D2:·1300.00,·Change:·300.00↵
   D3:·155.00,·Change:·35.00↵
   D4:·3500.00,·Change:·800.00↵
   D5:·1450.00,·Change:·470.00↵
   D6:·1023.00,·Change:·273.00↵
Total:·10128.00,·Change:·1578.00
Average·sales:·1688.00
Division·with·highest·sales:4
```

Here's my code:

My Code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int divs = 6;
    int qtrs = 4;
    double errorCheck;

    double[][] sales = new double[divs][qtrs];
    double[] qtrsales = new double[qtrs];

    int highestDiv = 0;
    int[] highestDivi = new int[qtrs];

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++) {
        for (int qtr = 0; qtr < qtrs; qtr++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter sales figures for division %d, quarter %d:", (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
            errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
            while (errorCheck < 0) {
                System.out.printf("Enter sales figures for division %d, quarter %d:", (div + 1), (qtr + 1));
                errorCheck = keyboard.nextDouble();
            }
            sales[div][qtr] = errorCheck;
        }

    }

    for (int qtr = 0; qtr < 4; qtr++) {
        System.out.printf("Q%d:\n", (qtr + 1));

        for (int div = 0; div < divs; div++) {
            qtrsales[qtr] += sales[div][qtr];
            System.out.printf("\tD%d: %.2f\n", (div + 1), sales[div][qtr]);
        }

        for (int qtrS = 0; qtrS < 1; qtrS++) {
            System.out.printf("Total:" + qtrsales[qtr] + ", Change:");
            System.out.printf("Average sales:" + (qtrsales[qtr] / divs));
        }

        for (int div = 0; div < 1; div++) {
            highestDiv = 0;
            if (sales[highestDiv][qtr] < sales[(div + 1)][qtr]) {
                highestDiv = (div + 1);
            }
            highestDivi[qtr] = highestDiv;

            System.out.println("Division with the highest sales:" + highestDivi[qtr]);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This question is far too broad in scope. This is a *question and answer* site - note that *question* is singular. You've asked 4 separate questions about different parts of your code. I'd suggest you stop trying to fix all the problems at once and concentrate on the first one. Once you solve that, you can move on to the second one, and so forth. We're not going to work on your entire assignment.

Comment: On that note, try to cut your problem down to size. What is the smallest piece of code you can construct that illustrates your problem. The act of doing this will help you to modularize your code and will often show you the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the output that I think you want:

```
Q1:
    D1: 1234.45
    D2: 1232.54
    D3: 23987.54
    D4: 1233.56
    D5: 234.56
    D6: 1234.45
Total: 29157.10
Average sales: 4859.52
Division with the highest sales: 3
Q2:
    D1: 234.56
    D2: 1234.45
    D3: 1232.54
    D4: 23987.54
    D5: 1233.56
    D6: 234.56
Total: 28157.21 (change: 28157.21)
Average sales: 4692.87
Division with the highest sales: 4
Q3:
    D1: 1233.56
    D2: 234.56
    D3: 1234.45
    D4: 1232.54
    D5: 23987.54
    D6: 1233.56
Total: 29156.21 (change: 29156.21)
Average sales: 4859.37
Division with the highest sales: 5
Q4:
    D1: 23987.54
    D2: 1233.56
    D3: 234.56
    D4: 1234.45
    D5: 1232.54
    D6: 23987.54
Total: 51910.19 (change: 51910.19)
Average sales: 8651.70
Division with the highest sales: 1
```

IMPORTANT: If that's not what you want, then I've managed to fail at following directions and you probably shouldn't listen to anything else I have to say.

This output was had by making a number of small changes. Of course, I'm not going to hand them over to you (that would be doing your homework for you, and for that I would need to charge you an exorbitant sum of money) so instead I'll just point you in the right direction.

To start with, there is this bit of code:

`for (int qtrS = 0; qtrS < 1; qtrS++)`

Study that line of code carefully and discover what it is actually doing. I'll give you a hint: it isn't *wrong* necessarily, but there is something you could do to improve it.

You have a similar loop further down:

`for (int div = 0; div < 1; div++)`

Study this one more carefully - it may appear to have the same problem as the previous, but it does not. Once you solve this riddle, your remaining issues will present themselves more clearly. (Note: if your 'fix' causes your program to crash - good. Keep going, you're on the right track.)

In addition, I'd like to offer the following advice for that final loop:

Your data uses a zero-based index. Looking at your code, you already know this. Your output in some cases is one-based (you print `Q1`, not `Q0`). Again, looking at your code, you already know this. My advice is to be consistent about how you deal with this indexing discrepancy. Specifically, always index your data using zero-based indexes and only `+ 1` those indices when printing the output for the user.

Now... about that Change calculation. If you don't know how to do something, try explaining the problem to yourself in very clear and precise terms (like writing a program, but without the overhead of language syntax, array indexing and all that other complicated mumbo-jumbo.) If you did, it might sound something like this:

"I need to calculate the change for quarters 2-4. This means that I need to print a change for each of those quarters (Q2, Q3, Q4). More specifically, I'll need three "change values". How would a change value be calculated? Starting at one quarter and figuring out how much changed to the next? That's just a subtraction. So all I really need is find a way to get those two values (for each quarter) so I can perform that subtraction. Oh, and I have to make sure to only do it for those quarters (2-4)."

Remember, the trick is to bob your head while talking to yourself in the car so people think you're singing along.

Good luck.

Comment: @paulin your advice is really good and informative I'll give it try. I'll see if I can do it.

Comment: If this works for you, don't forget to mark it as an answer.